# Search by hashtag Twitter API v1.1 - No Returns Old Results

Tags: php, api, twitter, hashtag

I'm doing a search for hashtags using the new api Twitter (v 1.1) and it works for some results. But for older tweets do not return a result.

My code:

```
    $this->load->library("TwitterAPIExchange", $settings);

    /** Perform the request and echo the response **/
    $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);

    /** URL for REST request, see: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/ **/
    $url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json";
    $requestMethod = "GET";

    //hashtag
    $hashtag = "#vmb2012";
    //Method search parameters GET
    $getfield = "?q=$hashtag&result_type=mixed&count=100";
    //Counter tweets
    $count = 0;

    /** Search global tweets for a hashtag **/
    $result = json_decode( $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)->performRequest() );      

    if(!empty($result))
    {
        //increases the qty of tweets
        $count = isset($result->statuses) ? count($result->statuses) : 0;

        //if you have more results, performs the query again                                
        while($result->search_metadata && isset($result->search_metadata->next_results))
        {
            //search parameters of the next result
            $getfield = $result->search_metadata->next_results;
            $result = json_decode( $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)->performRequest() );
            $count += count($result->statuses);             
        }                   
    }

    echo "Hashtag: ".$hashtag." <br>";
    echo "Counter: ".$count;
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: As the answer says, you won't get **exact** tweets via the Twitter API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [dev.twitter.com](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets)

> Please note that Twitter's search service and, by extension, the Search API is not meant to be an exhaustive source of Tweets. **Not all Tweets will be indexed or made available via the search interface**.

I hope this was helpful

Comment: sorry for the delay in responding. But yes, that's exactly what I saw in the documentation. Alternatively a calculation made ​​by adding the new amount of tweets per day. Thanks for the help!